# socket.emit() not workign in socket.on('connect') in client

Tags: websocket, socket.io

My server code:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(3000, {
    cors: {
        origin: '*',
    },
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
   .........
});
```

My client code:

```
var socket = io.connect('localhost:3000');
socket.on('connect', function() {
    console.log(socket);
    socket.emit('init', 'Hello');
});
```

When I start the browser with client page and immediately after connection I'm receiving socket object in the console, but not anytime socket.emit is happening when looking into Network/WS tab in Dev tools.

[image]

Whats wrong?

Comment: You have not posted how you handle the init event on the server side.

Comment: Sorry. Now edited.